# No data written in to csv file. What's wrong in this class based approach?

Tags: python, csv

I have a project in that I initialize two log files in a class using `'setup_image_and_model_folders'` as follows.

```
results_header = ['Image count','File path','Wafer','Die','Name']

def setup_image_and_model_folders(self):
    self.open_results_log()

def open_results_log(self):
    # creating log file to write all inspected files
    log_file = open(self.logs_csv,'a')
    self.log_writer = csv.writer(log_file)
    
    #creating results log file which only includes metal detected
    csv_file = open(self.results_csv,'w')
    self.csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    if not os.path.exists(self.results_csv):
        self.csv_writer.writerow(results_header)

def write_results(self, data):
    self.csv_writer.writerow(data)

def write_logs(self, log):
    self.log_writer.writerow(log)
```

It creates the CSV files at two locations specified in the path. However, 'results_csv' is empty although I write the header.
Also no matter how many times I call '`write_results`' and '`write_logs`', nothing gets written into the files.

This is the first time I am using the class-based approach to update files. If I write the same thing in one function, it works fine.

What is wrong here?

Comment: The code you shared doesn't do anything it just defines methods. You didn't even include the whole definition of the class.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to close the file.

Try to store the `csv_file` as `self.csv_file` and run `close(your_class_instance.csv_file)` after writing.

If this solves the issue, try to rewrite your code so that it uses a context manager, via:

```
with open(path_to_file, "w") as file:
   ... write to file ...
```

then `file` will be closed automatically.

Comment: What's the best way to keep the updates without closing? The reason is that I want to make sure no one opens the file while running

Comment: @PCG try with flush()

Comment: Opening a file does not "block" anyone else from opening this file.  A process can open the same file twice.  Maybe you want to add a mechanism in your class to protect against that.  Something like `self.is_file_opened = True` once the file is opened and then test that in the function opening the file.